# How to upload file to SharePoint using REST API in C#

Tags: c#, rest, sharepoint, postman

I am trying to upload a file to SharePoint using C#. I am getting access token, but I am not able to upload file, I have to gone through few references and tried to see if I can do it using Postman at least.

I am getting below error when I tried with Postman:

> <m:message xml:lang="en-US">The HTTP method 'GET' cannot be used to access the resource 'Add'. The operation type of the resource is specified as 'Default'. Please use correct HTTP method to invoke the resource.</m:message>

Here is my Postman request:

[image: Here is my Postman request]

Can I get any reference for REST API call using C#

Comment: Searching StackOverflow or the web at large for the title of your question returns many helpful results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a POST instead of GET for that operation.

Check out [this link](https://toolsqa.com/postman/post-request-in-postman/) to find out how.